# Exercising stock options in a private company when the strike price is higher than current FMV

Tags: united-states, stocks, employee-stock-options, option-exercise

An employee leaving our Private Subsidiary wants to exercise his stock options, despite his  strike price being higher than the current valuation ($1.00 vs $0.84).

Was wondering what the tax implications are for this?  I assume he will just pay the Company the strike price, because there is no gain.

Comment: Country, sir? I was just about to offer a response till I realized,"they might not do it that way in Elsewheristan, or Othercountryville, for that matter.

Comment: This is for an option exercise in USA

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - Elsewhereistan has already adopted the central bank policies from Othercountryville.  Keep up with the news!

Answer (score 1):

For the employee, this is an identical tax situation to an at-the-money option purchase. They're buying an asset with a specific cost basis.

For the company, you are just issuing shares from treasury as authorized... debit cash, credit additional paid-in-capital and equity. There is no tax consequence for this money received.